# How to use geonames api to validate zip code / postal code against a country?

Tags: java, json, rest, geonames

The requirement is to validate whether zip code really exists or not in a specific country??

Country = US
State = California

I wants to know how to call geonames API using REST to get country code by zip code?  I would prefer an output in a JSON format over XML.

Answer :

Refer 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientGet {

    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/get
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       try {

        URL url = new URL("http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON?postalcode=94536&maxRows=1&username=demo&country=US");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
           (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }

}
```

Thanks Mkyong!

Answer (score 0):

They have a file a [country info](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt) file,There are `regexes` for about 150 countries.

You need to create GeoNames model. This model will handle creating, storing, and returning the value of our GeoNames WebServices request.

For more info - http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html